# Where can I get the amcl.patch and stage.patch

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make multi_robot_collision_avoidance work, but I cannot get the amcl.patch mentioned in the installation document. Without those I have got some error, like missing stage_ros.msg. I am running on indigo, how can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281732/where-can-i-get-the-amcl.patch-and-stage.patch/) by [superttmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/29204/superttmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-04**:
What patch and documentation are you referring to?

**Comment by [superttmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/29204/superttmm/) on 2018-02-05**:
[this](http://wiki.ros.org/multi_robot_collision_avoidance?distro=fuerte) is the document I am referring to. @jayess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions for applying the patch from the wiki page that you refer to say

> patch AMCL:
>
> ```
> roscd collvoid/..
> mv amcl.patch ../navigation
> roscd navigation/..
> patch -p1 < amcl.patch
> ```

If you look at the above commands, you'll see that the file `amcl.patch` is should be in the root of the repo (one directory above `collvoid/`). I looked at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/daenny/collvoid) and found the file by switching to the "forward-predict" branch. So, if you need to apply that patch, switch to the "forward-predict" repo and you'll have the patch.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1